# How to force Visual Studio preprocessor case sensitivity with #includes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, c-preprocessor

If you have a header file named ThisIsAHeaderFile.h, the following will still locate the file in Visual Studio:

```
#include <ThisIsAheaderFile.h>
```

Is there a way to enforce case sensitivity so that the `#include` will result in an error?

Comment: I have seen this be a problem when working with Unix code bases that may use two versions of the same file name, but with different case.

Comment: One reason this would be useful is for crossplatform codebases where you want the Windows developers stop inserting case errors into the codebase.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't, because the Windows file system is itself case-insensitive.

If you could get into a situation where you had both RICHIE.h and richie.h, it might make sense to control case sensitivity, but you can't.

Comment: You can write iF.. includes ... boiler plate to do this for each file. <Shudder>

Comment: Actually, that's not quite right. NTFS retains the case of filenames as part of POSIX compliance, but maps everything to upper case when doing file operations.

    http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2005/01/16/353873.aspx

Comment: C++ runs on more than just Windows boxes.

Comment: I rember having a problem where it turned out there were two files (RICHIE.h and richie.h (they differed only in case)) Win manipulated the first one it found in the directory structure.

Comment: @WolfmanDragon: This question is specifically about Visual Studio.

Comment: @WolfmanDragon: Because it runs on different platforms it has to take into account that some platforms are simply not case sensitive in the file system.  Hence the behavior.

Comment: @RichieHindle, & Chris Lively, You guys have missed WolfmanDragon's point. I run into this very often. Our windows dev team uses visual studio, and breaks the linux build due to incorrect capitalized headers. A lot of unnecessary cycles could be eliminated if there was a way to make cl.exe be case sensitive for includes.

Comment: @Lorenz03Tx: Good point, but sadly I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Visual Studio could case sensitively compare the name from the file system with the filename from the include statement... Nothing is preventing that.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out that this is **not** an unsolvable problem as many tries to point out to the OP. The case insensitivity is beside the point. The point is as [Lorenz03Tx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340343/lorenz03tx) explains in a comment, even though the file system is case insentitive the case is retained, so it can be controlled.

Such a counter measures is really great to have when doing cross platform development, and prevents much after work when the code is compiled for the other platform. Not to forget that making the build process more picky you would induce better habits for the developers, as they gradually will be more consistent how they include and name files.

TL;DR

One solution is to use a script that simply scans the source files for include statements and tries to match them along the include paths. Such a script could be added to visual studio post-build events, and thus run at every build, or (inspired by [krlmlr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946850/krlmlr)) use the preprocessor of a compiler that enforce case sensitivity.

Comment: You don't need a script to find #include statements, just pass the compiler option that outputs the full path of the list of files processed (for GCC, that's `-MMD`)  That takes care of the hard step, leaving it necessary only to script fetching the actual directory entry (on Windows, that's `FindFirstFile`) and compare.

Answer (score 1):

It is (used to be?) possible to create files with the same name but case differences on NTFS.  Maybe someone with cygwin can verify this.

[MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625)

Even then, however, it's impossible to access more than one of these at a time from a normal Windows application.

Answer (score 1):

While it might not be possible to enforce this from within Visual Studio, one could implement a quick check by running only the preprocessor on the C/C++ source. This will run quickly enough to be practicable even as post-commit hook in a version control system, and err if the case in file names has been mismatched. So:

- Configure your build system in Linux to support preprocessor-only runs (`-E` with `gcc`/`g++`)
- Implement a preprocessor-only run as post-commit hook, triggering an early notification to the responsible person and/or to someone willing to routinely fix these errors

Of course, this assumes a VCS as central storage for the code.

Comment: This is a great solution, another one would be a simple script or running preprocessor as pre commit on the committers machine, and let the user clean up itself.

Comment: @daramarak: How will that help if the committer runs a case-insensitive file system?

Comment: As script is able to detect the case, and while the mingw preprocessor is case insensitive (and it seems to have no options to turn this on), gcc in cygwin will be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Both FAT and NTFS are case insensitive file systems.  Foo and fOO are the same file as far as they are concerned.  Although the Windows OS will preserve the case you use for a file.  If you name a file ThisIsAheaderFile.h it will show up that way in the file system. Although all system function calls to open that file can use any casing they want.

Comment: No, NTFS is case sensitive (or can be made to be with a registry setting). Win32, however, is case-insensitive. Just FYI, since the answer is wrong and all...

Answer (score 0):

Also having similar problem when trying to build under linux; not full solution...
If you **Find in Files** *#include* by VS and copy result to **textarea**, you will get sorted CSV with include file name, original path and list of files in 3rd column (columns are tab delimited)
Easy to check solution/wide and in case there are not much case problems it should be easy to replace them?

```js
function readIncludes(t)
{
    var s = t.value.split('\n');
    var res = {};
    for(var r in s)
    {
        if (r == 0) continue;
        var dq = s[r].indexOf('(');
        var p = s[r].substr(0, dq);
        var p2 = s[r].indexOf(':', dq);
        p2 = s[r].substring(0, p2);
        dq = s[r].indexOf('#', dq);
        var i = s[r].substr(dq);
        var ip = i.replace(/#include\s+/, "");
        if (!ip) continue; // *#includes.*
        var st = '<>""';
        if (st.indexOf(ip[0]) < 0) continue; // *#include*\S+
        st = st[st.indexOf(ip[0]) + 1];
        ip = ip.substr(1, ip.indexOf(st, 2) - 1);
        if (!ip || ip[0] == '/') debugger
        if (!res[ip]) res[ip] = [];
        res[ip].push(p2);
    }
    var resSorted = [];
    for(var r in res)
    {
        var shortR = r.replace(/.+[\\/]/, ""); // include file
        resSorted.push(shortR + "\t" + r + "\t" + res[r]); // \tpath\tplaces
    }
    t.value = resSorted.sort().join('\n'); // sort again long lines of results
}
```

```css
html,body,textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea onchange="readIncludes(this)">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion: All C++ compilers should at least warn if the case of the #include in source differs from the case on disk on case insensitive systems. On case sensitive systems it should warn if there is a file than when compared as case insensitive would match the include and is a different case than the include. Just my opinion, having been bitten by this way too many times...

In my experience doing cross platform development the best way to deal with this is to compile on a case sensitive system looking for the case conflicts and then fixing them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34250901)